# No sound on front panel headphones

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I'm trying to enable my front panel headphones on Ubuntu 16.04. Alsamixer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vxq9u.png The thing is that if I enable my front mic, I can hear noise in my headphones, but there is no sound from ubuntu - firefox or other sound sources like vlc or etc.

Is my alsa configuration correct?

Here is my Alsa-info:

```
!!################################
!!ALSA Information Script v 0.4.64
!!################################

!!Script ran on: Mon Feb 27 09:55:25 UTC 2017


!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS \n \l DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS" NAME="Ubuntu" ID=ubuntu ID_LIKE=debian PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS" HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/" SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/" UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial


!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer:      Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
Product Name:      To be filled by O.E.M.
Product Version:   To be filled by O.E.M.
Firmware Version:  FD
Board Vendor:      Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
Board Name:        970A-DS3P


!!ACPI Device Status Information
!!---------------

/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0103:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0A08:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C01:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0C:00/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:00/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:01/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:02/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:03/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:04/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:05/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:06/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:07/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:11/status   15


!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    4.4.0-64-generic
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         x86_64
SMP Enabled:       Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     k4.4.0-64-generic
Library version:    1.1.0
Utilities version:  1.1.0


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------

snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_intel


!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

 0 [SB             ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI SB
                      HDA ATI SB at 0xfe300000 irq 16
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xfe080000 irq 30


!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)


!!Advanced information - PCI Vendor/Device/Subsystem ID's
!!-------------------------------------------------------

00:14.2 0403: 1002:4383 (rev 40)
    Subsystem: 1458:a182
--
01:00.1 0403: 10de:0be3 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: 1462:8094


!!Modprobe options (Sound related)
!!--------------------------------

snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_usb_caiaq: index=-2
snd_usb_ua101: index=-2
snd_usb_us122l: index=-2
snd_usb_usx2y: index=-2
snd_cmipci: mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2


!!Loaded sound module options
!!---------------------------

!!Module: snd_hda_intel
    align_buffer_size : -1
    bdl_pos_adj : 32,32,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    beep_mode : N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N
    enable : Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y
    enable_msi : -1
    id : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    index : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    jackpoll_ms : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    model : auto,(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    patch : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    position_fix : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    power_save : 0
    power_save_controller : Y
    probe_mask : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    probe_only : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    single_cmd : N
    snoop : -1

!!Module: snd_hda_intel
    align_buffer_size : -1
    bdl_pos_adj : 32,32,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    beep_mode : N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N
    enable : Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y
    enable_msi : -1
    id : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    index : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    jackpoll_ms : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    model : auto,(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    patch : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    position_fix : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    power_save : 0
    power_save_controller : Y
    probe_mask : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    probe_only : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    single_cmd : N
    snoop : -1


!!HDA-Intel Codec information
!!---------------------------
--startcollapse--

Codec: Realtek ALC887-VD
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x10ec0887
Subsystem Id: 0x1458a182
Revision Id: 0x100302
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x5f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 CLKSTOP EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
GPIO: io=2, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=1, wake=0
  IO[0]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[1]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
Node 0x02 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x41d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Front Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="ALC887-VD Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x40, nsteps=0x40, stepsize=0x03, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x40 0x40]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x03 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x41d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Surround Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x40, nsteps=0x40, stepsize=0x03, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x40 0x40]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x04 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x41d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Center Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="LFE Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=2, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x40, nsteps=0x40, stepsize=0x03, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x40 0x40]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x05 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x41d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x40, nsteps=0x40, stepsize=0x03, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x40 0x40]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x06 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x611: Stereo Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x5f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x07 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x08 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10051b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Capture Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="ALC887-VD Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x10, nsteps=0x2e, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x2e 0x2e]
  Converter: stream=1, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x23
Node 0x09 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10051b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Capture Volume", index=1, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Capture Switch", index=1, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="ALC887-VD Alt Analog", type="Audio", device=2
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x10, nsteps=0x2e, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x22
Node 0x0a [Audio Input] wcaps 0x100711: Stereo Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x1f
Node 0x0b [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Front Mic Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=1, ofs=0
  Control: name="Front Mic Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=1, ofs=0
  Control: name="Rear Mic Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Rear Mic Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Line Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=2, ofs=0
  Control: name="Line Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=2, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x17, nsteps=0x1f, stepsize=0x05, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x9f 0x9f] [0x9f 0x9f] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 10
     0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1c 0x1d 0x14 0x15 0x16 0x17
Node 0x0c [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x00 0x00]
  Connection: 2
     0x02 0x0b
Node 0x0d [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 2
     0x03 0x0b
Node 0x0e [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 2
     0x04 0x0b
Node 0x0f [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x00 0x00]
  Connection: 2
     0x05 0x0b
Node 0x10 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x611: Stereo Digital
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Default PCM Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
  Device: name="ALC887-VD Digital", type="SPDIF", device=1
  Converter: stream=5, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x5f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x11 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400781: Stereo Digital
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x99430130: [Fixed] SPDIF Out at Int ATAPI
    Conn = ATAPI, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x10
Node 0x12 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400401: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x4037c040: [N/A] CD at Ext N/A
    Conn = Analog, Color = UNKNOWN
    DefAssociation = 0x4, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x13 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x14 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Front Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0001003e: IN OUT HP EAPD Detect Trigger
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x01014010: [Jack] Line Out at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Green
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=05, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x0c
Node 0x15 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x00000036: IN OUT Detect Trigger
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x0d
Node 0x16 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x00000036: IN OUT Detect Trigger
  Pin Default 0x
```

Comment: What kind of noise? Some hardware lacks proper insulation, but pops are from the speaker power turning on or off suddenly.

Answer (score 0):

Your `alsamixer` Front volumes say 'MM', which means they're muted. Select them with the arrow keys and press <kbd>M</kbd> to toggle mute.

If you don't have a separate microphone jack (small pink one), then it's probably a combo jack that supports TRS plugs and TRRS plugs. Unfortunately the latter's OMTP standard was ignored by Apple who chose the CTIA/AHJ layout that swaps mic and ground pins, and [a custom button protocol](https://help.longtailproducts.com/hc/en-us/articles/207970396-Smartphone-Headset-Standards-Apple-iPhone-AHJ-CTIA-OMTP). A converter plug should fix the layout if needed.